# Is it possible for a Telegram bot increase Post view count?

Tags: c#, telegram

I want to simulate that my bot has read the messages in my channel. By default with the telegram api it seems it is not possible to increment the post view count. Does anybody know how can I achieve that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

The post view count only counts unique views from user accounts.
So the answer is: No, you can not increment views with bots.